# Kentico SMTP server application

Tags: kentico

Was this removed in a hot fix? I'm running 9 with 30 and i can't see it. My 9 with hotfix 5, has the app.

I am able to set the server in the Setting, but can't see the SMTP app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP Servers app is only available with an EMS license.  So if you have done any of the following since your hotfix application, it may not show:

- Downgraded your license key
- Checked the box in settings to "hide unavailable user interface items"
- Changed your macro hash string in web.config (need to resign macros then)

Comment: That could be it. I'll double check the what type of licence was created.

Comment: Would it hold, that if there is no SMTP servers app, kentico can't send email?

Comment: If you specify the SMTP server in the Settings>System>Email, it will use that vs. anything in the SMTP app.

Comment: Thanks, then i have other issues not related to kentico. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It should be there.  Are you logged in as a global administrator? Have you recently changed any permissions?

If you run this Query in SQL you can get the URL to the application to see if it loads or any errors are thrown:

```
SELECT LOWER(cu.ElementGUID) FROM dbo.CMS_UIElement cu
WHERE cu.ElementName    = 'Administration.SmtpServers'
```

This will give you the guid that you can use in the URL:

[DOMAIN]/Admin/CMSAdministration.aspx#[GUID]